# Android Dropbox SDK on Kindle - URL scheme does not work / is not found

Tags: android, dropbox, url-scheme, kindle-fire

I am trying to run my Android 4+ on a Kindle Fire. Everything works fine but the connection to Dropbox. The app uses the latest Dropbox SDK and on normal/Non-Kindle Android devices everything works as expected:

When `dropboxAPI.getSession().startOAuth2Authentication(activity)` is called within the app the browser comes up and shows the Dropbox webpage with a user login. Once the user is logged in he can decide to allow or decline the apps access the Dropbox account. After doing this the user is re-directed back to app by calling a custom URL scheme that is defined in the app manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard"
    android:launchMode="singleTask" >
    <intent-filter>
        <!-- Change this to be db- followed by your app key -->
        <data android:scheme="db-xyzMyAppKeyXYZ" />

        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

This workes fine on all Non-Kindle devices. On Kindle the user is not re-directed back to the app but the following error message is shown within the browser:

> Webpage not available: 
>   The wepage at `db-xyzMyAppKeyXYZ://1/connect?outh_token_secrete...` faild to load. 
>   Unknown error.

Obviously there seems to be some problem kind of problem with the scheme. But would kind of problem could that be and how can it be solved?

Comment: It looks like you do have the URL scheme registered properly. Did this work previously? It seems like custom URL schemes may just not be supported by the system/browser.

Comment: While it works without any problem on other Android devices it fails on Kindle devices. Maybe it is a problem with the Silk browser. Problem is, that this is the default browser and most users will just run into this error. Is there any way to bypass this?

Comment: Unfortunately it does sound like a problem with this browser, and I'm afraid that being the case there's probably not much we can do to change that, beyond requesting this be fixed in the browser. (Do you know if this previously worked in this particular browser though?) Alternatively, users could install the Dropbox for Android app.

Comment: Cross-linking with the Dropbox API forum: https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=120149

Answer (score 2):

in case someone encounters the same problem I want to share the answer I just received from Amazon:

> Fire devices do NOT support Dropbox.

I have no idea why Dropbox should not be supported by the Android based Fire devices since it works pretty well on all other Android devices. My best bet is, that this about some dispute between Dropbox and Amazon. Maybe Amazon wants to promote its own cloud services.

Could have saved me some hours of debugging if Amazon would communicate this more clearly. Maybe this answer can save you some time :-)

Comment: Thankfully this no longer appears to be the case: I can't get the URL scheme to work, but it DOES work if I install the native app via https://www.dropbox.com/mobile